# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GraphDef

Tags: java, tensorflow, mode

I use java reload the tensorflow pb model. I put the model in the resource package(intellij IDEA). It works ok when I run it on my pc. But When I compile it to .jar and run it on another computer. it goes wrong as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GraphDef
at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:130)
at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:114)
at com.xunlei.algo.analysis.LstmSeqModel.<init>(LstmSeqModel.java:66)
at com.xunlei.algo.analysis.LstmSeqModel.main(LstmSeqModel.java:90)
```

My code is shown as follows:

```
InputStream is = LstmSeqModel.class.getResourceAsStream("/lstmSeq.pb");
int count = is.available();
System.out.println(count);
graphDef = new byte[count];
is.read(graphDef);
g.importGraphDef(graphDef);
sess = new Session(g);
```